Reaction of NH3, primary and secondary amines with acid chlorides and anhydrides
Looking at the reaction of NH3, primary and secondary amines with an acid chloride and anhydride in a textbook, it says 2 equivalents of NH3 are needed to yield the corresponding amide product.
What will be the structure of the product if only 1 equivalent of NH3/amine was allowed to react with an acid chloride/anhydride?

You'll still get the amide, but only part of the substrate gets there.
When ammonia reacts with an acyl chloride to make a primary amide, the other product from the nucleophilic substitution is $\ce{HCl}$, and that will react with part of the ammonia supply to make the salt $\ce{NH4Cl}$ instead of the intended amide. The second equivalent of ammonia would compensate for this side reaction. A similar thing happens with an anhydride substrate (forming a carboxylic acid) and with a primary or secondary amine as the nucleophile.
